Cassandra Backups questions
I am very very new to cassandra.
As I slowly wrap my head around it I have  questions about backups.  (be gentle)
I was asked to build a processing machine for scientific application we use  which uses cassandra database for the application and the work we do in research.
That was easy enough , its only a 2 node cluster as that's all the App needs and its working fine in testing. It is an on premise setup because of the type of work and size of work we do. with 2 Nodes I am trying to understand the best option to backup both the Nodes . IE attach a local Disk and copy or snapshot the data onto this Disk on each Node and do that in parallel I believe so both nodes do this together.
Is this even correct? Should I be doing something different?
We cannot use this in cloud.(not allowed to) I understand the basics but any guidance or advise is very much appreciated. I have started reading about medusa  but thought I would ask the community.
At this stage the database wont grow too big that it requires more nodes  but this may be a future consideration.


attach a local Disk and copy or snapshot the data onto this Disk

That should work fine.
What is your replication factor (RF)? If you're running with RF==2 on 2 nodes, then they should each have identical data. So you probably only really need to run backups on one of the nodes.
Also, have a look at Cassandra Medusa. It's an open source backup system for Apache Cassandra®. Using Medusa should be easier than coordinating backups yourself.
https://github.com/thelastpickle/cassandra-medusa
